# Expectation and Variation of dependent RVs

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, covariance

This is a really nice question, and while I can think of a solution to both parts, I wonder if there's a more elegant one to the latter:

> A fair 6-faced dice is tossed once. In a box there are 6 coins, numbered 1 to 6. Each has $\frac{1}{i}$ chance to land Head up, where $i$ is the number of the coin. The coin is chosen based upon the result of the dice, and is thrown until it lands Head up.
>
> We define X as the RV representing the result of the dice-throw, and Y as the RV representing the number of times the coin is tossed until (including) the toss where it lands Head up.
>
> Find E[Y], Var(Y).

I can define Y as the summation of each $Y_i$ representing the tossing of the i-th coin (each $Y_i$ being a geometric RV), each with a probability of $\frac{1}{6}$ of happening. That means:

$$Y=\sum_{i=1}^{6}\frac{1}{6}Y_i$$

That way it is extremely easy to find E[Y]. However, Var(Y) remains difficult to find, due to the need to find so many Covariance between each $Y_i$, and thus the need to find $E[Y_i * Y_j]$ for each. Is there a simpler, more elegant way to do Var(Y) instead of computing each? Perhaps I can state something regarding them, due to their exclusiveness (I know that if $Y_i$ happened, $Y_j$ certainly didn't)? I am a bit lost regarding it, and I am rather sure there is a simpler/faster/more elegant way to do this, yet unsure of what it is. Perhaps conditional probability can come into use?

Any directions/hints/suggestions will be extremely appreciated!

Comment: Have you learned about _conditional_ distributions? If so, the problem is easier; if not, the calculation can still be carried out but takes longer and is less elegant.  If you _do_ know about conditional distributions, look for the _total variance formula_ which says that the variance of $Y$ is the mean of the conditional variance plus the variance of the conditional mean.

Comment: agreed with above, use the conditional variance formula, i.e. $Var(Y) = E(Var(Y|X))+Var(E[Y|X])$. In fact you used the conditional expectation formula $E[Y]=E[E[Y|X]]$ for question 1. I think this question was an intended as an exercise for these two formulae.

Comment: I see, thank you! Just one more question: $Var(Y|X), E[Y|X]$, both are short-cut for the summation of Y given each possible value of X, correct?

Comment: The formula for $Y$ is wrong.

Comment: I can see the elegant solution now for both parts using the conditional formula, but still curious - why is the formula for Y wrong @Did?

Comment: To begin with, because Y is a random integer while your formula can yield, say, a result of 17/6.

Comment: Thank you, I see the faulty now.